# Disable automatic screen turn-off even if I am not near the phone during call

Tags: calls, android-10, samsung-galaxy-s-9, screen-timeout

I have a non-rooted Samsung Galaxy S9 running on Android 10. If I am placing my phone on a table during a call (using an external headset), it will turn off the screen after a couple of seconds.

How do I disable that?

I prefer not to install new apps nor rooting the phone.